# Python: is there a common way to simplify the code which used in sql

Tags: python

This is my code

```
    a1 = "a1"
    a2 = "a2"
    a3 = "a3"
    bb1 = [a1,a2]
    bb2 = [a1,a2,a3]

    db = BasicMysql(host="*",port=,user="*",password="*")
    db_values = "INSERT INTO db.bb1 values" + "('%s','%s') " %(bb1[0],bb1[1])
    db.exec_insert(db_values)  //db.exec_insert is packaged which is same as "cursor.execute(query)"

    db_values = "INSERT INTO db.bb2 values" + "('%s','%s') " %(bb2[0],bb2[1],bb2[2])
    db.exec_insert(db_values)
```

it maybe a good way/expression to "db_values". any idea?

maybe pseudocode like this:

```
all_sql = [bb1,bb2]
for one in all_sql:
     db_values = "????"
     db.exec_insert(db_values)
```

---

The following is my APIs which packages MySQLdb APIs.

import MySQLdb
         class BasicMysql: // define a class

```
def __init__(self,**kw):
        self.host = kw['host']
        self.port = kw['port']
        self.user = kw['user']
        self.password = kw['password']

            try:
                database_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.host,port=self.port,user=self.user,passwd=self.password,local_infile
= 1,charset="utf8")
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                sys.exit(e)
            self.conn = database_conn

        def exec_insert(self,query):
            conn = self.conn
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            try:
                cursor.execute(query)
            except Exception,e:
                print Exception,":",e

            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()

        def __exit__(self):
            try:
                self.conn.close
            except Exception,e:
                 print Exception,":",e
```

Comment: why do you do all this assignments just to `print` the values?

Comment: Well, yes, this particular code can be boiled down to one hardcoded `print` statement. You have probably abstracted your actual question way too much from your real scenario to be useful. Or you need to clarify more what particular aspect of this needs to be simplified.

Comment: thanks, i have added some comments.

Comment: You should rather be using the prepared statement API which your DB driver pretty surely offers instead of interpolating values into strings!

Comment: @deceze sorry, but i don't know your means clearly. "db.exec_insert" is a my defined APIs which use MySQLdb API. what about "prepared statement API"?   Anyway I add my code how to define "db.exec_insert" ?

Comment: I can't find specific documentation for the MySQLdb package, but the API seems to conform to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods), which means you can use it like `cursor.execute('INSERT ... VALUES (%s, %s)', (a1, a2))`. Note that this is *not string interpolation*, it separates the query from the values (a.k.a. prepared statements).

Comment: @deceze  -  now i can't ask another question. do you know what need i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found "locals" which could meet my needs:

```
getVar = locals()
a1 = "a1"
a2 = "a2"
a3 = "a3"
bb1 = [a1,a2]
bb2 = [a1,a2,a3]
all_sql = [bb1,bb2]
for one in all_sql:
     db_values = ",".join([str([getVar[i]) for i in all_sql])
     db.exec_insert(db_values)
```

my unclear expression and poor English may troubled others :(